# What is the relation between database connection pool number and web application user number?

Tags: database

For example, I have set 20 as databse connection pool number.Does it mean that there are at most 20 users can access database from web applicaiton at the same time and the 21st user have to wait for vacant connection?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you web backend handle connections.

If you start a transaction at the beginning of the HTTP request and give it back at the end, there can be no more clients than there is databases connections.

If you do fine-grained transactions, another client can come in in-between two transactions.